# Übersetzung von "I can explain that to you tomorrow -- if you want, of course"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> I can explain that to you tomorrow -- if you want, of course.

Mit diesem Satz drückt der Sprecher aus, dass er die Sache erklären kann, aber nur, wenn sie der Hörer wissen möchte. Wie sagt man das auf Deutsch? Geht das Folgende?

> Ich kann dir das morgen erklären -- wenn du willst, natürlich.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternativ zu `Veredomon`s Antwort (und ein bisschen näher am Original) wäre:

> Das kann ich dir/Ihnen morgen erklären – natürlich nur, wenn du/Sie willst/wollen.

Answer (score 5):

Ja, aber Folgendes finde ich schöner:

> Wenn Du willst, kann ich Dir das morgen erklären.

Im Deutschen ist es üblich, dass man sich selbst zuletzt nennt ("Nur der Esel nennt sich zuerst"). Das „natürlich“ verschwindet dann allerdings, ich halte es jedoch nicht für nötig.